# Django: Heroku migrations resulting in an error

Tags: django, heroku, django-south

I've been finishing up my first Django app and have run into a snag with migrations in Heroku. I migrated with South locally and then attempted to move those migrations to the database on Heroku.

When I ran:

```
heroku run stentorian/manage.py syncdb migrate report
```

I received the following error:

```
['/app/stentorian', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', '/app', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python27.zip', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Error: Command doesn't accept any arguments
```

I've researched this and can't seem to find how to resolve this. Prior to this, I installed the django-flaggit app to my application, which doesn't use migrations, and had to use a traditional syncdb to get the tables set up in Heroku. I'm wondering if this had an affect.

If anyone has any insight into this issue, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is actully calling two different commands in a row: `syncdb` and `migrate`.

The usual workflow with south is to run syncdb to sync all your non-south-supported apps, and then migrate, to work on south-supported apps. Actually, if you just run syncdb with south installed, it will tell you which apps are unsynced and must be migrated.

So, to summarize:

```
heroku run stentorian/manage.py syncdb 
heroku run stentorian/manage.py migrate report
```

Comment: Many thanks! Migrations can be a bit confusing at times.I thought I may had caused issues by syncing the flaggit app and then trying to migrate.

Comment: Yes that happens, sometimes you sync the app with migrations, for that you can "fake" migrations like `migrate report --fake`, which will apply migrations without actually doing anything. See south docs for more.